# How to install FFMpeg in WampServer 2.1 (Windows XP)

Tags: ffmpeg

I m using php 5.3.5 on windows xp and now i try to install ffmepg from this link http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php-win32-all.zip
when i resart my wamp server i got this warning 
PHP Startup:ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with modle API=2006013
PHP  compiled with module API=20060626
These options need to match
Kindly someone guide me how i correct this problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download ffmpeg package from http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-php-5.3-win32-all.zip
2. Unzip package
3. Move php_ffmpeg.dll to php extension dir (usually c:\wamp\php\ext)
4. Move all other files to Windows\System32
5. Add extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini (usually c:\wamp\php\php.ini)
6. Enable enable_dl=on to php.ini (usually c:\wamp\php\php.ini)
7. Restart all services in apache server